# AsyncSelect setting data from api

Tags: reactjs, react-select

how can i store the data inside asyncselect from mongoose , the data returns an array and the Async loadOptions is always empty , how can i store the data inside AsyncSelect

```
const getPortal = async (e) => {
   
    try {
        await axios.post("/getPortal").then(res => {
            const data = res.data.portal;
            return data.portal;

        })
       
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

 <AsyncSelect loadOptions={getPortal} />
```

here is what it returns

[image]

Comment: Don't mix `async`/`await` with callback-based notifications. Most likely it's due to using a callback where you're already awaiting.

Answer (score 0):

Use React's state management, this also assumes you are using React hooks:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const getPortal = async (e) => {
    const res = await axios.post("/getPortal");
    const resData = await res.data.portal;
    setData(resData);
}

 {data && <AsyncSelect loadOptions={data} />}
```

Comment: Just make sure that you are calling getPortal() whenever you want to fill in the select data

Comment: i tried that but it returns an empty array in the beginning and the AsyncSelect component still empty , i also tried to infinite loop the data state with useEffect but the AsyncSelect component still empty with no option value

Comment: can you console.log(res) right after your await axios.post

Comment: I can debug if you put your code in a sandbox

Comment: here is it sorry for taking a while i added the api data to the state because i couldn't get my api link because its on a local machine 

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-babycat-qwvurl?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I made some changes to get you going, I did not realize this was using the react-select package. You may need to tinker with it a bit more.

Comment: can u tell me what did you change because i cannot see the changes ^^

Comment: Sorry, here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-butterfly-1o0b3i

Comment: there is an error when you press on the select i get a typical error

Comment: Yeah that might be due to the sandbox, i followed the documentation and if you look at the console it should be correct

Comment: maybe there is something wrong with react-select its still not working , i will try to find another way to put the data into select option , sorry for the trouble ^^